# detekt doesn't generate report

Tags: kotlin, maven-plugin, detekt

I'm building my project by maven. The `detekt` configuration was added based on the [official documentation](https://arturbosch.github.io/detekt/mavenanttask.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- This can be run separately with mvn antrun:run@detekt -->
            <id>detekt</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target name="detekt">
                    <java taskname="detekt" dir="${project.basedir}"
                          fork="true"
                          failonerror="false"
                          classname="io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.cli.Main"
                          classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath">
                        <arg value="--input"/>
                        <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin"/>
                        <arg value="--config"/>
                        <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/sv_detekt.yml"/>
                        <arg value="--filters"/>
                        <arg value=".*/test/.*,.*/target/.*,.*/resources/.*"/>
                        <arg value="--output"/>
                        <arg value="${project.build.directory}/detekt-reports"/>
                        <arg value="--output-name"/>
                        <arg value="checkstyle-result"/>
                        />
                    </java>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt</groupId>
            <artifactId>detekt-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RC8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Then, I'm trying to execute it by the following command: `mvn antrun:run@detekt`

The result is the following:

```
$ mvn antrun:run@detekt
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< com.my:opd >--------------------------
[INFO] Building opd 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (detekt) @ opd ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.295 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-10T11:46:02+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

looks fine but the folder `${project.build.directory}/detekt-reports` is not created and there are not any reports. What I did wrong?

Comment: Can you run `mvn` with `-X` to get more info on what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where is the issue however when detekt is executed through the maven tool in the intellij, it works fine. May be the problem in windows terminal...